# Adding the product of an element of a list to an existing list in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am trying to take a list of lists (like shown below)

```
list = [[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3],
        [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
        [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6],
        [6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2],
        [7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]
```

compute the product of all the elements of each list, and append the result back onto the original list.

So, for example, if I were to take the list I posted above, what I would want it to look like is this:

```
list_2 = [[5000940,[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3]],
          [0,[3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0]],
          [0,[1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6]],
          [0,[6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2]],
          [0,[7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]]
```

The code that I have written so far takes in the list, outputs the products, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it properly appended to the exiting list and I was hoping someone would be able to show me how to do this.

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    global products
    products = []
    list_prod = reduce(mul, list[i], 1)
    #products.append(list_prod)
    print products
```

Comment: What does *"can't seem to get it properly appended"* mean, exactly?

Comment: Meaning I can't seem to get my output list to look like the example in list_2. Does that help?

Comment: ...so what *does* the output look like? And why have you called your own variable `list`?

Comment: It looks like you want to PREPEND the product. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, @AdamSmith, that's right, I had never heard the term PREPEND the product but that's exactly what I want to do. @jonrsharpe, you're right about the name of the list...I changed it before I asked the question. The output I get from the code looks like this `[5000940][0][0][0][0]`

Comment: @ADT append is to add something to the end, prepend is to add something to the beginning. In this case it's probably better to generate a NEW list than the prepend the product, since prepending to a list is a very inefficient function (it has to move every element in the list to the next index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are like me, and find list comprehensions difficult to read(Esp in the future). You may find the below code useful. Additionally, avoid using "list" as a name for the variable. As its a library function name.

```
num_list = [[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3],
    [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
    [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6],
    [6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2],
    [7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]

num_list_fin = []

for num_item in num_list:
    num_item_u = [reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, num_item)]
    num_item_u.append(num_item)
    num_list_fin.append(num_item_u)

print num_list_fin
```

This would give the output:

```
[[5000940, [7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3]], [0, [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0]], [0, [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6]], [0, [6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2]], [0, [7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks @doubleo, this was exactly what I was looking for. I had never seen `lambda` functions before and was just trying to understand what this piece of code does: `num_item_u = [reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, num_item)].` Would you be able to explain that?

Comment: Sure ! Okay, so reduce basically takes a iterable(As second argument, in this case num_item) and applies a function of two arguments(in this case x*y) to all the elements(taken two at a time) of the iterable from left to right - to 'reduce' it to a single value.  Hope that clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
from operator import mul
from pprint import pprint

lst = [[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3],
        [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
        [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6],
        [6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2],
        [7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]

lst[:] = map(lambda e: [reduce(mul, e, 1), e], lst)

pprint(lst)
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/g3xVR6)

Comment: why are you using `lst[:] =` ?

Comment: to modify the list in-place in case there are other references pointing to it

Comment: @d0c I don't think that's necessary. `lst=` will do the same thing.

Comment: nope, it won't. compare these two: http://ideone.com/sWqsfu http://ideone.com/lqYteV

Comment: the OP is creating a new list not modifying the original

Comment: the OP mentioned appending to the original list, which clearly implies in-place modification

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3],
        [3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
        [1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6],
        [6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2],
        [7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]


[[reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, line)] + line for line in list]
```

Gives me

```
[[5000940, 7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6],
 [0, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2],
 [0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: I think you should change the variable name from `list` and maybe point out why it is not a good idea to use list as a variable name

Comment: absolutely but that's what the person asking the question was using so i wanted to keep it simple. -1 for using reserved words :)

Answer (score 0):

It may make things clearer if you use a helper function.

```
def listprod(lst): return reduce(mul, lst, 1)

print( zip(map(listprod, mylist),mylist) )
```

Change the tuples to lists if you really need that.